# Changing Activity to AppCompatActivity uses more RAM?

Tags: android, android-activity, memory, android-appcompat

Our app always took a maximum of 60MB immediately after login (when the `MainActivity` performs `setContentView(R.layout.mainActivity);`)

Recently we updated our activities to `AppCompatActivity`. I noticed that this change adds about 30MB of RAM (The app now takes 90MB RAM immediately after login).

I confirmed this by reverting back to `Activity` and saw the reduction in memory.

Why is this happening? Does this mean I am doing something wrong when using `AppCompatActivity`?

I also tried changing all the UI components to AppCompat (`TextView` to `AppCompatTextView`, `ImageView` to `AppCompatImageView`, etc..) but I did not see any difference.

Any advice would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Adding the MainActivity's layout xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainActivity"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:padding="15dip" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/selectContactBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="contacts"
        android:src="@drawable/select_contact_enabled"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/selectMediaBtn"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/selectMediaBtn"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/selectMediaBtn" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/destName"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/CallNumber"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/CallNumber"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/CallNumber"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/CallNumber"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/CallNumber"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/selectMediaBtn"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:contentDescription="mypic"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/mediaicon"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/CallNow"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/inviteButton"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:contentDescription="invite "
        android:clickable="false"
        android:src="@drawable/invite"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/CallNow"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/CallNumber"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:hint="To...."
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:phoneNumber="true"
        android:maxLength="10"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:completionThreshold="1"
        android:inputType="textAutoComplete|text"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/selectContactBtn"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/selectMediaBtn"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/selectMediaBtn"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/userStatusPositive"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/userStatusPositive">

        <requestFocus />
    </AutoCompleteTextView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/CallNow"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="Call Now"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/selectProfileMediaBtn"
        android:contentDescription="mypic"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/avatar"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/CallNumber"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/CallNumber"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/CallNumber"

        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/selectContactBtn"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/selectContactBtn"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/clear"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/clear"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/CallNumber"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/CallNumber"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/CallNumber"  />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="RingTone Name "
        android:id="@+id/ringtoneName"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:hint="No Ringtone Was Chosen !"
        android:layout_above="@+id/CallNow"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/selectMediaBtn"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/selectMediaBtn"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/selectContactBtn"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/selectContactBtn" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/userStatusPositive"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/CallNumber"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/CallNumber"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/CallNow"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/CallNow"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/CallNow"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/CallNow"
        android:src="@drawable/positive"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/userStatusNegative"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/CallNumber"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/CallNumber"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/CallNow"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/CallNow"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/CallNow"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/CallNow"
        android:src="@drawable/negative"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fetchuserprogress"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/CallNumber"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/clear"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/CallNumber"

        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/CallNumber"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/CallNumber"

        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/CallNow"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/CallNow"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/sb__text_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/sb__text_size"
        android:id="@+id/mediaStatusArrived"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ringtoneName"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/selectMediaBtn"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/selectMediaBtn"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/sb__text_size"
        android:src="@drawable/doublepositive" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/sb__text_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/sb__text_size"
        android:id="@+id/ringtoneStatusArrived"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/selectMediaBtn"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/sb__text_size"
        android:src="@drawable/doublepositive" />

</RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#ffff"/>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: That surprises me that it take much more memory, however I would not recommend to use all the compat views. The AppCompatActivity injects them as far I remember just on demand.

Comment: Thanks. So I will leave all views as non-AppCompat. But it also surprises me that it takes more much more memory, and I am unsure how to solve it.

Comment: Just as a hint, the compat views let you tint your controls, not sure if this is relevant for you. However as long you use the `AppCompatActivity`, this will been done automatically.

Comment: Well, not using the other compat `Views` is not a solution, because the app would look weird on older Android versions, with new ActionBar, but old Buttons, and that stuff. I'll research a bit now, perhaps I'll find a solution.

Comment: @Nom1fan How many activities would use AppCompatActivity?

Comment: @Max Well, currently we have 5 activities in our app (This can change because we are still under initial development). As far as I understand `Activity` is deprecated, so all of them would use `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: @Nom1fan Well, for five `Activities`, the RAM use is still quite heavy... Hm. What is the app supposed to do? Perhaps that may be a trigger for this RAM use problem.

Comment: The issue is this RAM usage occurs even before the app does anything at all, and before starting any other activities. Just the MainActivity performs setContentView() on its onCreate, and bam! 90MB. The same flow using Activity, only uses 60MB. Would it help to show the mainActivity.xml?

Comment: You use many images, what are their dimensions?

Comment: We know we have issues with the drawables, and are working on resizing all of them to fit the drawable folders (xxhdpi, xhdpi, etc...). But do you think this is the issue? Is there any reason drawables would have this effect when using AppCompatActivity but not when using Activity?